# Unable to <use> inside <defs> in svg

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to duplicate a pattern, but I want the elements I duplicate to be outside the `<defs>`. Why doesnt it work?

```html
  <svg width="750" height="750">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250">
        <use href="foo" x="0" y="0"></use>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#pat)" width="1000" height="500"></rect>
    <rect id="#foo" fill="red" width="15" height="15"></rect>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`

```html
<svg width="750" height="750">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="pat" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <use xlink:href="#foo" x="0" y="0"></use>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#pat)" width="1000" height="500"></rect>
    <rect id="foo" fill="red" width="15" height="15"></rect>
  </svg>
```